# Undefined index - app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 145

Tags: product-images, ce-1.9.1.0

Fresh install of 1.9.1 and I can not get the images to swap on the product page.

I've followed the setup here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches

But I have no idea why the images are not changing. If anyone has run across this please let me know, my searches have been fruitless.

Notice: Undefined index: red  in /home/xxx/public_html/adev/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: red  in /home/xxx/public_html/adev/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php on line 151

[image: colors configured on configurable product]

Comment: http://adev.hbc6.com/index.php/test.html in case you need it

Comment: It appears, despite the hosting company saying otherwise, there's an issue with the hosting company that's causing the problem. I have, using the same data and setup, created a working magento 1.9.1 with proper image swapping on a bluehost server, so the issue is with the hosting company and not the files. Thank you all for being so exhaustive and assisting and I will report back what's causing the issue when there's a resolution.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the issue here is that you do not have labels assigned to the images (thanks for the screenshot - quite helpful!).

Starting at [line 139 of `Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php#L139) there is a loop which deals with these images, and it seems that the array index is not valid (makes sense in your case):

```
foreach ($searchValues as $label) {
    $imageKeys = array();
    $swatchLabel = $label . self::SWATCH_LABEL_SUFFIX;
    $imageKeys[$label] = array_search($label, $imageHaystack);
    if ($imageKeys[$label] === false) {
        $imageKeys[$label] = array_search($mapping[$label]['default_label'], $imageHaystack);
    }
    $imageKeys[$swatchLabel] = array_search($swatchLabel, $imageHaystack);
    if ($imageKeys[$swatchLabel] === false) {
        $imageKeys[$swatchLabel] = array_search(
            $mapping[$label]['default_label'] . self::SWATCH_LABEL_SUFFIX, $imageHaystack
        );
    }
    foreach ($imageKeys as $imageLabel => $imageKey) {
        if ($imageKey !== false) {
            $imageId = $mediaGallery['images'][$imageKey]['value_id'];
            $images[$imageLabel] = $mediaGalleryImages->getItemById($imageId);
        }
    }
}
```

If you add labels to the images, see if that solves the problem. If it does, please consider creating an account (or logging in) at the Magento site and reporting the bug at http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking.

Comment: This answer is beautiful :-)

Comment: NB I have yet to install 1.9.1.0 (yeah, I'm the worst evangelist EVER), but this certainly looks correct *and* it seems in keeping with those "unanticipated" but seemingly obvious bugs one finds after release...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the add labels to images, I've tried on the config-product page to use swatch-blue, blue-swatch, Blue-swatch, et al.. In the admin, Manage Label Options, the colors are all set and the configurable product image labels are the same text. Use magemojo for hosting, PHP 5.4.35

Comment: Have you tried uploading large images to the simple products instead (ie red image to simple product with red color)?

Comment: I have tried adding images to all the associated simple products, adding image labels to those images as well. I think I've tried every combination of image label names on both the configurable and simple products, including using upper case, lower-case, mixtures, making sure there are no errant spaces anywhere in the labels, swatch image names, changing file permissions, and I'm just at a loss.

I even tried adding "color" to the label options in the code above. I've contacted my hosting company, but they didn't seem to have any answers about it maybe being a server setting issue.

Comment: I can't post an answer, but maybe this helps:
To fill the swatches, fill the labels in your screenshot (in the configurable product) with 'red-swatch' and 'blue-swatch' (mind the lowercase).
To get the main-images to switch, set a 'base image' in the simple products. It should be selected automatically.

I can't spot any differences from my test-install from the frontend, If you want I can have a look at the admin.

Comment: SOLVED: the problem was eAccelerator causing the issue, the hosting company turned it off and it works as expected